# VBA Combine multiple workbooks into one

Tags: vba, excel

I am stumped! I am trying to copy data from multiple workbooks in a folder and paste them into one Master workbook. I have a loop that will go through each workbook in a folder, copy the data and then paste it into the Master workbook. The problem is, I need the data to be pasted onto a new column each time. For example data from workbook1 should paste into column A, workbook2 should past to column B and so on.

I can get the code to paste the data from each workbook but it keeps copying it into one row. How do I get it to move to the next column instead of moving onto the next row?

```
'Description: Combines all files in a folder to a master file.
Sub MergeFiles()
    Dim path As String, ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long
    Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook
    Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range
    Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer

    RowofCopySheet = 2 ' Row to start on in the sheets you are copying from

    ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    path = "C:\testing"

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xl*", vbNormal)
    If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Do Until Filename = vbNullString
        If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
            Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
            Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
            CopyRng.Copy Dest
            Wkb.Close False
        End If

        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Range("A1").Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that everything is working okay - you just need to change the destination column from A, to B, to C, ... as the macro continues on.

Here's one way you could do it.

Add this function to your code (above/below your current sub):

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Then replace your `Do Until...` loop with this:

```
Dim col As Long
col = 1
Do Until Filename = vbNullString
    If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & "\" & Filename)
        Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
        colLetter = Col_Letter(col)
        Set Dest = shtDest.Range(colLetter & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
        CopyRng.Copy Dest
        Wkb.Close False
        col = col + 1
    End If

    Filename = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks so much BruceWayne! You have no idea how helpful that was, I really appreciate it! It is 99% working, just one little snag. The data from each workbook is now pasting to a new column each time, however it seems to start the new column on the row where the previous row finishes. For example, if the data on column A ends on row 3, the data on row B pastes onto row 4. Any thoughts?

Comment: @sarbear_85 - Try taking out the ` + 1` in that `Set Dest = ...` line.  That's looking for the last row, then adding another. If you take that out it should work.

Comment: I tried that but no luck. When I took out + 1 it pasted the data in B3 instead of B4 for example, so it took it up one row.

Comment: @sarbear_85 - Where *should* the data start? Should it literally just go from A1, then next iteration, B1, next iteration C1, etc...?  So **copy** `xx1:xx100`, paste in other workbook `A1:A100`, then next **copy** say `yy1:yy10`, paste to `B1:B10`?

Comment: That's exactly right, it should paste into the first cell in each column.

Comment: @sarbear_85 - Ah! Then just do `Set Dest = shtDest.Range(colLetter & "1")`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your dest like this.

from

```
Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
```

to

```
Set Dest = shtDest.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)(1, 2)
```